# how to generate the histogram data in java using commons math3.0

Tags: java, statistics

I want to generate a histogram from a set of data that i have using apache commons math 3.0 library. I have been looking on their documentation ( http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/index.html), but could not find out. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Frequency class, chech API doc here: http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/Frequency.html

Comment: but how can i define the bins with Frequency.. i think its not supported.